# Flex: Delete visual element

Tags: apache-flex

I have a `VGroup` in my application that contains several custom components of type `MyComponent`. Now I have a delete method in `MyComponent` that should once ran delete the element from the `VGroup`. I know I should use `parentDocument.vgroupId.removeElement()` but what to pass as a reference?

Note: I want to do the delete within a method from `MyComponent`

**UPDATE**: here is my source:
In my main application

```
<s:VGroup id="vgroupId" width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Now I add my custom component as:

```
 var cust:FunctionElement = new MyComponent(); // MyComponent extends spark Panel
 vgroupId.addElement(cust);
```

And from `MyComponent` I call

```
parentDocument.vgroupId.removeElement(this) // get this error => TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert global@5ed30d1 to mx.core.IVisualElement.
```

If I cast it as `this as IVisualElement` I get an error that it is equal to `null`

Comment: I just noticed you are adding the MyComponent as a FunctionElement.. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example will show how you can do it..

ExampleApp.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">     
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function button1_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                vgroup.addElement(new MyComponent());
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup id="vgroup" top="30" />
    <s:Button label="Add" mouseUp="button1_mouseUpHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Define MyComponent.mxml like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100" height="35">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.VGroup;
            protected function button1_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // A few useful traces to see what's what and where.
                trace(this);
                trace(this.parent);
                trace((this.parent as VGroup).getElementIndex(this));
                // But all we actually need is ...
                var vgroup:VGroup = (this.parent as VGroup);
                vgroup.removeElement(this);
                // (this.parent as VGroup).removeElement(this); // Would also work fine.
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button mouseUp="button1_mouseUpHandler(event)" label="Kill me!"/>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: Already tried it. And get the error "ArgumentError: null is not found in this Group."

Comment: what does parentDocument.vgroupId.getElementIndex(this as IVisualElement) return? can you post the source?

Comment: Great, can you let me know what - parentDocument.vgroupId.getElementAt(0) - returns? - also set a breakpoint just before the removeElement and see if you can gather any more info in the debugger. Oh, also do a typeof(this) to see what it thinks 'this' is at the calling scope.

Comment: It return null; "ArgumentError: null is not found in this Group."

Comment: Was this for ... parentDocument.vgroupId.getElementAt(0) ? ...  according to that error, there's actually nothing in your vgroup

Comment: @Adnan ... look at the example, accessing the VGroup via parent works fine (and is a better way than going up to the parentDocument)

Answer (score 0):

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <mx:Script>

            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import spark.components.Button;

            private function getNewElement():IVisualElement
            {
                var btn:spark.components.Button = new spark.components.Button();
                btn.label = "button " + myContent.numElements;
                return btn;
            }

            private function addFirstElement():void
            {
                myContent.addElementAt( getNewElement(), 0 );
            }

            private function removeFirstElement():void
            {
                if( myContent.numElements > 0 )
                    myContent.removeElement( myContent.getElementAt( 0 ) );
            }

            private function removeLastElement():void
            {
                if( myContent.numElements > 0 )
                    myContent.removeElementAt( myContent.numElements - 1 );
            }


    </mx:Script>


    <mx:Button label="addFirst" click="addFirstElement();" />
    <mx:Button label="removeFirst" click="removeFirstElement()" />
    <mx:Button label="removeLast" click="removeLastElement()" />
    <mx:Button label="removeAll" click="myContent.removeAllElements()" />

    <mx:VBox id="myContent">
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```